# Error in compiling product.tpl using smarty

Tags: php, css, templates, smarty, smarty3

I have tried to compile the [this](http://www.codeshare.io/ywPex) tpl file using smarty. My php file is [this](http://www.codeshare.io/Qx8uW). But I am being shown the error message

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template ".\templates\product.tpl" on line 94 "var doesntExist = '{l s='This combination does not exist for this product. Please choose another.' js=1}';" unknown tag "l" <-- thrown in C:\wamp\www\Smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 94

Can anyone please help me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears at:

```
var doesntExist = '{l s='This combination does not exist for this product. Please choose another.' js=1}';
```

The question is what is here `l` - is that Smarty function? If yes, it appears it's not loaded properly and if it should be plain text from some reason, you might try putting it into `{literal}`:

```
var doesntExist = '{literal}{l s='This combination does not exist for this product. Please choose another.' js=1}{/literal}';
```